# Building a website that uses twitter data: Caching best practices?

Tags: caching, twitter

I'm developing an application that makes use of twitter data. It will associate tweets with entities created by the users, as well as allow other visitors to tweet on the entity page, associating that tweet with the entity as well.

My first thought was to create a local store of all tweets matching a particular search phrase that relate to the entities, associating them via the user...

This works fine, except what happens when a user deletes their tweet from their timeline? it will still be present on the entity page because I'm using my local cache of tweets...

What is the best practice for working with an ongoing set of twitter data? I don't need to backlog it for say a year or anything, but I do want to make sure it's cached long enough to be useful, while still syncing with their actual timeline (in case tweets are deleted)

Comment: I thought perhaps using a WebRequest and checking the status code (assuming 404 for a deleted tweet). unfortunately, Twitter returns a 200 (OK) result for a deleted tweet! So how am I supposed to check my cache for deleted tweets without hitting my rate limit?

Answer (score 0):

You could purge your cache every so often.  I've been working on this same problem lately and I can't find any good information on it.

I'm just going to pull down full tweet information for the time period matching my cache and check to see if there are any tweets existing in my cache that aren't in the api results.  Then remove those from the cache.  I'll probably set it to be done once a day per user.

Comment: Are you still doing this? I thought about checking the user timeline, but this requires me to authenticate as the user, doesn't it? what if the user has a private timeline? do you check every individual tweet? won't that hit your limit pretty quick?